# How to create xml with this style via C# code?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create via C# code XML like this:

```
<Title>    
      <A>
            <aa=aa,cc=cc,dd=dd/>
      </A>
      <B>
            <bbbbbbbbbbbbb.udl/>   
      </B>
</Title>
```

With what code should i create tree like thist? How to put symbols like "=" and "." inside the name?

Comment: You can't put things like that inside the name - that is not XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only by using a StringBuilder, since the sample you gave is not valid XML.

Did you mean to use syntax like:

```
<aa foo="bb" bar="cc"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [xml serialization](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173), and change the name of elements:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="bbb.udl", IsNullable=false)]
  public class BBB
  {
    public BBB()
    {
      //default constructor
    }

    private String someField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use periods but the equals sign is not a valid character for an xml tag.

XmlWriter will helps writing xml.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is not XML since it cannot be parsed by a XML-parser. You can use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check what is XML and what is not.

I would make my own class - `HackyMLBuilder` that as a `StringBuilder` inside. This class can have methods for adding nodes, etc.

The "=" inside "names" are in XML called attributes inside elements or tags and must be declared like this: `<a aa="aa" bb="bb" />`